# django: View to delete html table row not taking effects in Database

Tags: python, django

I have a page that displays rows from a db table. I added a button to each row that is designed to delete the row upon its click as well as redirect toward a deleted confirmation page. Everything seems to work, unless that nothing gets deleted in the database table.

Here is what my views.py look like:

```
def ProductsView(request):
     
     queryset = Products.objects.all()
     products_list = list(queryset)
     request.session['context'] = products_list
     
     #table =  ProductsTable(queryset)
     #context = {'table':table}
     return render(request, 'inventory.html', {'products_list':products_list})
                                               


def DeleteProduct(request, Id):

     Products.objects.filter(ProductId=Id).delete()
     return render(request,'delete_confirmation.html')
```

and here is what the html page look like, including the code for the delete button

```
<table class="table text-center table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                   
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">NAME</th>
                    <th scope="col">CATEGORY</th>
                    <th scope="col">TAG NUMBER</th>
                    <th scope="col">STOCK ON HAND</th>
                    <th scope="col">DELETE</th>
                   
                    
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="background-color: white">
                    {% for Products in products_list %}
                    <tr>
                        
                        <td>{{ Products.ProductId }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Products.ProductName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Products.ProductCategory }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Products.ProductTagNumber }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Products.StockOnHand }}</td>
  
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'delete_confirmation' Id=Products.ProductId %}" style="color: white">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

here is what urls.py looks like:

```
   path('inventory.html', ProductsView, name="inventory"),
    path('delete_confirmation/<int:Id>', DeleteProduct, name="delete_confirmation"),
```

and when I print `Id` in console inside of the ``DeleteProduct``` view, it ouputs the correct Id value

I can't find out what I am doing wrong, I have been at it all day and need a pair of fresh eyes to look at it! Does anyone has a clue on what is wrong here?

Comment: Share urls.py and you print Id to your console.

Comment: mkalioby, just updated my post

Comment: Please share the Product models as well and console output when the button is clicked

Comment: why dont u try before you delete Product you should try to check if this Product exist `if Products.objects.filter(ProductId=Id).exists()`,if not exist you can just return any page you like